# codeacademy “Functions & if/else”

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code? I can not figure out why it keeps coming up bad. Been working at it and have also looked on here for help and I'm still doing something wrong.

```
// Write your function below. 
// Don't forget to call your function!
var sleepCheck = function (hours)
{
    if (hours >= 8) 
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe too much!";
    else 
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
};

sleepCheck(10);

sleepCheck(5);

sleepCheck(8);
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with your return value.

Comment: you execute your function, but you dont wrap it with any `console.log` or `alert` statements, so nothing *should* happen.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = sleepCheck(10);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return` try to replace it a `alert` so you can see the output. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mc4yj2of/).